how to show preprocessed text after applying PreprocessText Widget in CorpusViwer and DataTable Widgets?
i cant see the preprocessed text after using PreprocessText Widget in DataTable and CorpusViewer Widgets
i see it only when i use WordCloud Widget , but i cant in DataTable and CorpusViewer Widgets
MY WORKFLOW :

CORPUS VIEW BEFORE PREPROCESS TEXT :

WORD CLOUD BEFORE PREP :

PREPROCESS TEXT WIDGET :

CORPUS VIEW AFTER PREP :

WORD CLOUD AFTER PREP :

DATA TABLE:

i cant see my text after preprocessed widget in data table or in corpus viewer unlike in word cloud , why ?
